# Get device browser data into my application in iPhone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, safari

My requirement is getting browser data(safari history) into my iOS application.
Is it passable? Can any one help me.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There is NO API to access Safari's browsing history.